# usort to sort by save date

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to sort and display the images by saved date. My code isn't sorting the images? I want the newest images first...

```
function my_sort($a,$b){
    if ($a==$b) return 0;
    return ($a<$b)?-1:1;
}

if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    $folder = htmlentities($_POST['val1']); 
}
if( isset($folder) ) {
$filetype = '*.*';
$filex = glob($folder.$filetype);
    $count = count($filex);
    $sortedArray = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $sortedArray($filex[$i]);
    }

$div= '';
usort($sortedArray,'my_sort');
foreach (glob($folder.$filetype) as $files) {   
        $div .= '<div class="typeS">';
        $div .= '<li><div class="itemTypes"><input type="image" src="'.$files.'"/><gt_descA>"'.substr($files,strlen($folder),strpos($files, '.') - strlen($folder)).'"</gt_descA></div></li>';
        $div .= '</div>';   
    }
echo $div;
}
```

Comment: Show the contents of your array

Comment: The contents are a lot of images in a folder (folder = $folder).

Comment: *Show us the contents*. Don't tell us where it comes from. We need the actual contents.

Comment: the contents looks like this  5-11-2013_item34123.png, 5-17-2013_item86466.png, 3-16-2013_item12317.png, ...

Comment: So the dates are in the file name? That's gonna make your job more difficult.

Comment: Isn't there a way to determine the saved date rather than trying to sort by the file name?

Comment: You can get the last modified date using `filemtime()`. If you add that to your array it would make sorting it easier.

Comment: i did this. But that doesn't sort? $sortedArray[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($files[$i]))] = $files[$i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach`, you're doing a `glob` again, rather than looping over your sorted array. Change it to `foreach ($sortedArray as $files) {`

Answer (score 0):

I made five changes to your code
1. your array was being populated using parentheses.  I changed it to populate using square brackets.
2. your array had no index to reflect the foreach loop.  I added an index. 
3. you were sorting by the file name.  I changed the array to have a last saved date index, and sorted by last saved date
4. after sorting, your final foreach loop used the original unsorted array.  I replaced the original array with your sorted array.
5. you had one too many closing braces.  I removed the closing brace on the last line.

```
function my_sort($a,$b){
    if ($a['filesavetime']==$b['filesavetime']) return 0;
    return ($a['filesavetime']<$b['filesavetime'])?-1:1;
}

if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    $folder = htmlentities($_POST['val1']); 
}
if( isset($folder) ) {
    $filetype = '*.*';
    $filex = glob($folder.$filetype);
    $count = count($filex);
    $sortedArray = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $sortedArray[$i]['filename'] = $filex[$i];
        $sortedArray[$i]['filesavetime'] = filemtime($filex[$i]);
    }

$div= '';
usort($sortedArray,'my_sort');
foreach ($sortedArray as $file) {   
    $div .= '<div class="typeS">';
    $div .= '<li><div class="itemTypes"><input type="image" src="'.$file['filename'].'"/><gt_descA>"'.substr($file['filename'],strlen($folder),strpos($file['filename'], '.') - strlen($folder)).'"</gt_descA></div></li>';
    $div .= '</div>';   
}
echo $div;
```